# UIbarbuttonItem image looks stretched/thicker

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I have added custom UIbarButtonItems on toolbar. Everything is created through NIB file. I see the images are stretched. My images are 20x20 and 40x40 for retina. They are png files and I ensured they dont contain any drop shadow and use anti-aliasing. Currently the toolbar looks like this.
[image]

If you see, the same images appear sharp when not added as a barbuttonItem but just as imageview. How can I fix this.

Comment: Check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101608/setting-image-for-uibarbuttonitem-image-stretched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to create your `UIBarButtonItems` in your viewDidLoad method?

Here is how I do with a `UINavigationBar` and all images looks fine:

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *rightButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
[rightButton setImage:rightButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 7.0, rightButtonImage.size.width, rightButtonImage.size.height);
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton] autorelease];


UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *leftButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:"img2.png"];
[leftButton setImage:leftButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 7.0, leftButtonImage.size.width, leftButtonImage.size.height);
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(method2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton] autorelease];
```

`method1` and `method2` are void methods: `-(void)method`

and to add 2 buttons on the right side, I do something like this:

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *rightButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3"];
[rightButton setImage:rightButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 7.0, rightButtonImage.size.width, rightButtonImage.size.height);
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(method3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *middleRightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *middleRightButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img4"];
[middleRightButton setImage:middleRightButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
middleRightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 7.0, middleRightButtonImage.size.width, middleRightButtonImage.size.height);
[middleRightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(method4) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton] autorelease], [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:middleRightButton] autorelease], nil];
```

For `UIToolbar` you have to add items like this:

```
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item1, item2, item3, item4, nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The images I had where not designed to be used with Interface builder and directly as a barbuttonItem. Going your route it worked!