# Incorrect image stretching in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is the following problem: I use an UIImage, and when I create it programmatically without setting image size my image is stretching by vertical with some issues. Look at the screenshot:

[image]

My code is:

```
[backButton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Also I have the image with the same name but prefix "@2x". What's the trouble it might be?

Comment: You know you can set the back button to have no text to give you just an arrow.

Comment: It's problem not only for the back button. It appears for each image created programmatically

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101608/setting-image-for-uibarbuttonitem-image-stretched

Comment: self.youuttonr.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: @Deepesh It's a better idea to vote to close the question as a duplicate rather than just linking to another SO post that answers the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set Back Indicator Image for UINavigationBar, not setBackButtonBackgroundImage for UIBarButtonItem

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"]];
```

The color of the image is controlled by the tintColor property.

Or use

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the large height of you UIbutton , try it by decreasing button's size.

Comment: I don't set height everywhere

Answer (score -1):

I would try adding an UIImageView as a subview to the button and setting image on the UIImageView

```
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Phone.png"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[button addSubview:imageView];
```