# How to customize iOS UINavigationItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I suppose that this is duplicate, but after a research I can not understand how to customise `UINavigationItem`.

I have custom `ViewController` (`VC`) which implements custom class `SWRevealViewController` (I need to create sliding menu). 
I have `Menu VC` and for each element of the menu I have `Navigation VC` with custom `VC` for each element of the menu.

To work each back button must be defined in `Designer` and to have outlet (I also added outlet for `navigation item`):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnSidebareMenu;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *niTitle;
```

In my `.m` file I have this code:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Custom title";

self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.btnSidebareMenu;
self.btnSidebareMenu.enabled=TRUE;
self.btnSidebareMenu.style=UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh;
```

to customise button and title for each `Menu element VC`.

I use this code to manage navigation to menu:

```
// Manage menu button
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController )
{
    [self.btnSidebareMenu setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.btnSidebareMenu setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

The navigation is ok, but I can not customise appearance of my Navigation bar:

I receive this:

[image]

, but I need something like this:

[image]

Any recommendations how to do that?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I managed to show proper size image, to change colour of the navigation bar, but I can not issue with `status bar` and `navigation bar`. When I set background colour of the `navigation bar` it fills also `status bar`. I see different solutions but they don't work or I don't understand them.

**REMARK:** I have several pages which are not part of `Navigation controller` in which my `status bar` is white. I need this also be the case for all my pages. (I need them to look like image 2, on which status bar is white and navigation section is blue).

Comment: if you want to change navigation bar background color on every screen... Then goto navigation controller.. click on navigation bar and go to property inspector and set BarTintColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of nav bar buttons, i guess you could drag and drop a `barButtonItem` into the nav bar using the `storyBoard`. Then you can set the `image` property of the `barButtonitem`.

Also note that the images you use for this should be the exact dimensions as it wont get scaled proportionately. So if your image is called `sandwich.png` then you should have the two following files in your assets :

1. `sandwich.png` - 22x22 pixels
2. `sandwich@2x.png` - 44x44 pixels

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101608/setting-image-for-uibarbuttonitem-image-stretched) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590170/how-big-should-a-uibarbuttonitem-image-be)

**UPDATE :** To make the icon white, or any other color, you can change the tint color of the `barButtonItem` in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: 10x, @ShahiM. I understand about the images size - this is still not proper dimensional image. I also need my image to be white (as its original colour is white).

Comment: @new2ios. ok. edited answer. let me know if anythings missing. cheers

Comment: @new2ios. You are using storyboards right? if yes, its always best to do as much UI designing as possible without using code. i,e. in the storyboard itself. this will ease lot of your work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to change the color of the icon:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

*The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items.*

Comment: Ok, but this changes the background colour of the navigation bar,  @Manuel Escrig. I also need that status bar is not covered by navigation bar.

Comment: Sorry I just edit it. Now is the correct way. Also in oder to prevent the navigation bar  from covering the status bar check the following answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953509/how-to-prevent-uinavigationbar-from-covering-top-of-view-in-ios-7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar Hope it helps!